# How to find the Expected value of urn-ball problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

An urn contains $6$ red and $4$ black balls. They are withdrawn from the urn, one at a
time and without replacement. Find the expected number of red balls chosen after the
first but before the third black ball has been chosen.
I am not sure how to tackle this. I need some help, please!

Denote by X the number of red balls chosen after the first but before the third black ball has been chosen. Define for $i = 1,...,6$.
$$ X_{i}= \begin{cases}
 & \text{1} \, \text{if red ball is chosen after the first but before
the third black ball has been chosen} \\
 & 0 \, \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$
The idea is to find $P(X = 1)$, which it has two components, namely, $P(\text{red ball chosen after 1st and before the 2nd black ball}) + P(\text{red ball chosen after 1st and before the 3rd black ball})$

Comment: $X_i$  notation is not clear to me. Can you clear me what $i$ is?

Comment: @OM: I'm *guessing* OP has numbered the red balls $1$ through $6$, and $X_i$ is $1$ if that numbered ball is chosen between the first and third black balls. But it would be good to get clarification.

Comment: @BrianTung is correct. if a red ball is drawn between the first black ball and before the third black ball then i = 1. i = {1,2,3,4,5,6} because in total there are 6 red balls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $4$ black balls so $4+1=5$ gaps before, between, and after them.

There are $6$ red balls so an expected $\frac65$ red balls in each gap.

We are interested in $2$ gaps so an expected $2 \times \frac65=\frac{12}5$ red balls in these gaps.

---

A similar approach:

- Consider a particular red ball $i$ and the four black balls.
- There are ${4+1 \choose 1}=5$ equally likely ways of ordering these,
- $2$ of which have ball $i$ between after the first but before the third black ball,
- so $\mathbb P(X_i=1)=\frac25$ and $\mathbb E[X_i]=\frac25$
- and $\mathbb E[X] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^6  \mathbb E[X_i] = \frac{12}{5}$.

Comment: @Henry, Thank you so much! I didn't consider the gaps before the first black ball, as well as the gaps after the third  and fourth black ball. I see where I made a mistakes. Oft-times, I found this type of questions are tricky.